# Quand utiliser « d’une manière/façon+adj » plutôt qu'un adverbe ?

Tags: expressions, usage, adverbes

Comment est-ce que les francophones utilisent les mots « manière » et « façon » ?

Utilisent-ils plutôt des adverbes dans leurs phrases ? Par exemple :

1. Il la regarde d’une manière innocente.
2. Il la regarde d’une façon innocente.
3. Il la regarde innocemment.

Y a-t-il une différence entre eux ou non ?
Quelle manière de parler est-ce qu’ils utilisent plus souvent ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Il n'y a pas de différence, sauf que l'adverbe au lieu de l'adjectif est légèrement littéraire et sera moins souvent employé mais on peut l'employer dans la langue parlée sans crainte de donner une impression de gaucherie.

Answer (score 1):

To complete @user168676 answer, there are some adjectives from which no adverb is formed. These include

> charmant, concis, content, crédule, fâché, hautain, possible.

An adverbial sense is then conveyed by some other form of expression, e.g.:

> d'une façon charmante, avec crédulité, il est possible qu'il vienne.

Also, some adjectives are used adverbially in certain set expressions, e.g.:

> parler haut/bas
>
> coûter/vendre/acheter cher
>
> voir clair
>
> s'arrêter court
>
> sentir bon/mauvais
>
> aller (tout) droit

Some other adjective forms are often used adverbially, e.g.:

> bref, fort, même, juste, soudain, tout